# Date selection based on current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL that selects a date range according to the current timestamp. The main idea is to select the records that happened (moveCompletedOn) in the date range between today at 0700 and 1900 hours, or between 1900 and 0700 of the next day, depending on the current timestamp at the moment the query runs.

UPDATE: For example:

- If the current timestamp is 10AM, then the selection must be: 0700 to 1900
- If the current timestamp is 3PM, then the selection must be also: 0700 to 1900
- If the current timestamp is 10PM, the selection must be 1900 from today to 0700 next day
- If the cureent timestamp is 2AM, the selection must be 1900 from yesterday, to 0700

UPDATE 2: Clarification

Just to clarify a bit, the selection should be DAY shift and NIGHT shift. From 7AM to 7PM and from 7PM and 7AM of the next day.

Whichever the time the query is run, the current timestamp will fall between those two selections. I just want to select all the records that happened in a shift, depending on the time the query runs. If it runs during the DAY shift, it will select all records of the DAY shift. If it runs on the NIGHT shift, it will select all records of the NIGHT shift.

I hope is a bit clearer now. If not, let me know, please.

Not being very good in SQL Server, I wonder how I can rewrite this piece of WHERE statement in SQL Server language:

```
   WHERE moveCompletedOn BETWEEN 
   TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - (12 / 24), 'DD-MON-YYYY ') ||  
      DECODE((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - (12 / 24), 'HH24MI') / 1200), 0, '07:00', '19:00'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') AND 
   TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - (12 / 24), 'DD-MON-YYYY ') ||  
      DECODE((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - (12 / 24), 'HH24MI') / 1200), 0, '07:00', '19:00'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') + (11 / 24))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: IOW, if `SYSDATE` falls in between 7 and 7 today, then you want tomorrow?

Comment: Can you please give the exact specification instead of the phrase "depending on the current timestamp at the moment the query runs."?

Comment: SQL Server uses the GETDATE() function to return the current date/time on the server.

Comment: Is this `Oracle` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro its oracle sql he wants converted to sql server sql

Comment: @PaoloCosta articulated exactly what I was trying to get at.  Need a bit more info.

Comment: Main post have been updated with requested information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL server,I would do something like this

```
select * from aa
where last_update between 
DATEADD(HOUR, 
    case datepart(hour, getdate() ) 
    when 1 then -3 
    when 2 then -7
    else  -10
    end , 
    GETDATE() 
 ) 
and 
DATEADD(HOUR,  
    case datepart(hour, getdate() ) 
    when 1 then -1 
    when 2 then -5
    else  -5
    end , 
    GETDATE() 
) ;
```

You can change the values to fit your needs.

Comment: But I don't want to ask for specific times. I just want to select all records on that range (7AM to 7PM or 7PM to 7AM) depending on the time the query runs. Check the UPDATE 2 on the main post. Thanks

Comment: My code allows you define the date range based on the the time you run the query.